# Created a struct, made a function it's returning objects of struct such as T1,T2 but brakeSystem().keys[] not working as T1.keys[] if brake equal to 0

Tags: c++, function, struct

```
#include <string>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct type {

    char keys[100];

};

type Tmain, T1, T2, T3, T4;

type brakeSystem();

int brake = 0;

int firstNum;

string Input = "5ABCD1BCD1CDE";

int main()

{

    firstNum = (Input[0] - '0');

    for (int i = 1; i < Input.size(); i++) {
        if (Input[i] != '1') {
            (brakeSystem()).keys[i - 1] = Input[i];
        }
        else {
            i++;
            brake++;
            brakeSystem().keys[i-1] = Input[i];
        }

    }

    cout << T1.keys[0];

}

type brakeSystem() {

    if (brake == 0)
        return T1;
    if (brake == 1)
        return T2;
    if (brake == 2)
        return T3;
    if (brake == 3)
        return T4;

}
```

Comment: Indent code 4 spaces, and include a blank line between code and non-code.

Comment: I've adjusted your code formatting but am unsure of your problem.  Are you getting a compilation error, or does it not behave properly when you run it?  [Edit] your question to include more details, including the full compiler errors and/or expected and actual behavior.

Comment: `brakesystem()` returns a *copy* of `T1`, `T2` etc. The original objects are not affected if you assign anything to these copies. You probably want to return pointers or references.